# What does "wrap" mean in this news headline?

Tags: word-meaning, headlinese

## U.S. Stocks Decline on Tepid Manufacturing Data: Markets Wrap

(from Bloomberg News (*[Source](https://finanza.repubblica.it/Bloomberg/2018/05/01/u_s_stocks_decline_on_tepid_manufacturing_data_markets_wrap-P80OUR6S972901_BLE/))*)

What does "wrap" mean?

Answer (score 1):

Its short for 'Wrap up', meaning to conclude.